# How can I detect inconsistent formulas?

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

Is there a way to automatically highlight inconsistent formulae, just like Excel does?

What I mean is if I have a range of cells with the same formula (structure) but one of those have a different formula, Excel will mark that cell as this is a potential error.

Is this function available in OOo Calc? I've looked at the Detective functions but none of those seem to do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel dispenses the inconsistent formula error largely through comparing the R1C1 formula equivalents to adjacent cells since the R1C1 version does not change. If you have numbers in A1:C9 and you total the numbers for each column in A10:C10, the formulas as *xlA1* are `=SUM(A1:A9)`, `=SUM(B1:B9)` and `=SUM(C1:C9)` but as *xlR1C1* they are all `=SUM(R[-9]C:R[-1]C)` (or `=SUM(R1C:R9C)` if absolute references are preferred). This makes it very easy for Excel to compare one formula against another to see if they are identical or not as viewed from the R1C1 perspective. So easy, in fact, that the operation can be performed as an on-the-fly background operation.

Unfortunately, OpenOffice Calc does not support R1C1 addressing outside of the `INDIRECT` and `ADDRESS` functions. This makes it much more difficult to compare the formulas in adjacent cells as each formula has to be have each internal cell/range address parsed *as referenced by the cell where the formula resides*. While this is possible through programming, it is not a native OpenOffice Calc capability. There may be some work done in this area (Google should know) but it would almost assuredly be an on-demand macro and not a background operation.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted to hear, but at least I can stop searching now. Thanks!